# Import Text File to phpmyadmin results in chinese characters

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a new Database with only 1 Column called Name (Varchar).

I have a textfile with Names looking likes this:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
...
```

Im trying to import this textfile into the Database:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/php8vywos' REPLACE INTO TABLE `tbl_test` LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`Name`)
```

In the database I do have fields now looking like this:

```
呥獴ഊ呥獴
```

Everything is set to UTF8-General.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `'/tmp/php8vywos'` use exact path of the file. Also check the database "Character Set"

Comment: Does your file have consecutive lines equalling `6AIJ`?  If so, then somewhere along the way that string (encoded UTF-8) has erroneously been read as UTF-16.  [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) loads files using [`character_set_database`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_database) unless an explicit `CHARACTER SET` clause is specified—however the documentation states that UTF-16 is not supported.  My guess is your `character_set_database` is nevertheless set to UTF-16 and this has caused the corruption you're witnessing.

Comment: Note also, if my comment above is correct, your lines appear to be terminated `\r\n` not `\n`.